# Dynamic dependencies in systemd

Tags: boot, systemd

I am trying to figure out how to specify dynamic dependencies for systemd that are specific to the current instance@.
In the `[Service]` section I can use `EnvironmentFile=` to load in variables using the `%i` variable, but I don't see any such thing for the `[Unit]` section.

Is there a way to load dependencies dynamically for specific units?

Comment: This is a very strange request. What is your use case here?

Comment: We have a software running that can run in several rolls, eg. master, worker, scheduler, etc. These roles are determined through configuration files. I would like to run these using systemd and have the configuration specified through a `%i` symlink, but I need to ensure that they start in the proper order: master < scheduler < worker.

Answer (score 1):

Also the `[Unit]` section allows specifiers like `%i` (see `systemd.unit(5)`)

daemon@.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=the daemon
Requires=other-daemon@%i.service
After=other-daemon@%i.service
[Service]
#....
```

Comment: Don't you mean `other-daemon@%i.service`?

Comment: other-daemon-%i.service would theoretically works too, but other-daemon@%i.service makes more sense in this context.